# why I am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I want sort this sentence "This account has an unconfirmed email address" by word length how can i do this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var some = "";
xx  = "";
 var vText = "This account has an unconfirmed email address";
    slitTxt = vText.split(" ");
    for(i=0; i <= slitTxt.length; i++ ){
        xx = slitTxt[i].length;
        some = $('body').append(xx+" ")

    }


 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Try `console.log(slitTxt)` and see what it returns.

Comment: Of by one error: `<=` rather than strictly `<`. It is definitionally true in any zero-indexed array system that `slitTxt[slitTxt.length]` is not defined. You can perform basic debugging to uncover this problem for yourself (e.g., checking the value of `xx` or `slitTxt[i]` in each loop iteration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are checking for lastindex+1 that does'nt exist or is undefined, remove equals to sign from loop condition replace "<=" with "<"

for example if array length is 5 using <= array.length means that  check for 5 or less than 5 ,here  first index is 0 and last is 4 so 5 is undefined

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var some = "";
xx  = "";
 var vText = "This account has an unconfirmed email address";
    slitTxt = vText.split(" ");
    for(i=0; i < slitTxt.length; i++ ){
        xx = slitTxt[i].length;
        some = $('body').append(xx+" ")

    }


 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error come because of this line :

```
for(i=0; i <= slitTxt.length; i++ )
```

An array is 0-indexed, which mean the first cell is `0` but the length would be `1`

So if you array contain 5 elements, the last one will be `arr[4]` or `arr[arr.length-1]`

So when your condition in the `for` loop is `i <= slitTxt.length`, the last iteration will be the same as `slitTxt[slitTxt.length]`, hence, it will be `undefined`.

Try that instead :

```
for(i=0; i < slitTxt.length; i++ )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` instead of for loop. Example:

```js
var vText = "This account has an unconfirmed email address",
    slitTxt = vText.split(" ");
slitTxt.map(function(val, ind){$('body').append(val + " ");});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><body></body></html>
```